# Hibernate @AttributeOverride columnNames of embedded CompositeType

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an `Amount` that is mapped to two database columns via a `CompositeUserType`:

```
public class Amount  {
    private BigDecimal value;
    private CurrencyCode currency;
}
```

It is used in this `Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
public class AccountBalance {
    private Calendar date;

    @Type(type = Amount.TYPE_DEF)
    @Columns(columns = {
        @Column(name = "amount"),
        @Column(name = "currencyCode")})
    private Amount amount;
}
```

Which is embedded multiple times here:

```
public class AccountStatement
    @AttributeOverrides(value = {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "date", column = @Column(name = "openingBalanceDate") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "amount.amount", column = @Column(name = "openingBalanceAmount") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "amount.currencyCode", column = @Column(name = "openingBalanceCurrency") )})
    @Embedded
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private AccountBalance openingBalance;

    @AttributeOverrides(value = {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "date", column = @Column(name = "closingBalanceDate") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "amount.amount", column = @Column(name = "closingBalanceAmount") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "amount.currencyCode", column = @Column(name = "closingBalanceCurrency") )})
    @Embedded
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private AccountBalance closingBalance;
```

Which results in:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ...AccountStatement column: amount (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

When I add `updatable = false, insertable = false` into the two columns in `AccountBalance` (as suggested in the exception text), schema validation is successful, but it fails on inserting data, because it tries to insert a `BigDecimal` into the next field in the `PreparedStatement` (not shown in my excerpt) which is a date.

So I want the values to be insertable and updatable.

**This leads to the conclusion that hibernate does not handle my `AttributeOverrides` annotation for the two columns of `Amount` correctly.**

I already tried multiple options:

1. `amount.amount` and `amount.currencyCode` (the column names, as in the excerpt)
2. `amount.value` and `amount.currency` (the field names inside `Amount` and the values returned by `getPropertyNames` of my `CompositeUserType`
3. just `amount` and `currencyCode` (results in AnnotationException: AttributeOverride.column() should override all columns for now)

Hibernate does not seem to really care too much what comes after the dot. I can change that to `amount.abcdef` and it will not throw an error, so I'm pretty much just guessing right now, how to override these column names.

When `Amount` is not inside an `Embeddable` it works just fine with this declaration, even when used multiple times in the same entity.

```
    @Type(type = Amount.TYPE_DEF)
    @Columns(columns = {
        @Column(name = "amount"),
        @Column(name = "currencyCode")})
    private Amount amount;
```

Does somebody have an idea?
All I could find to that topic was only related to Embeddables and not CompositeUserTypes inside Embeddables.

I'm using hibernate-5.1.2-final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've since submitted a pull request to Hibernate, that was merged recently, which will allow this to work:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11465

The way this patch works, you will need to specify the same override name twice, so in your example it will be:

```
@AttributeOverrides(value = {
    @AttributeOverride(name = "date", column = @Column(name = "openingBalanceDate") ),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "openingBalanceAmount") ),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "openingBalanceCurrency") )})
@Embedded
@Basic(optional = true)
private AccountBalance openingBalance;
```

(The order has to be what it is in the `CompositeUserType`.)

This is now merged, so it will be released in the next release of Hibernate 5.2, which will be 5.2.11.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [hibernate guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables) you should add `@Embeddable` to `AccountBalance`.
Furthermore I would recommend, to use @Embeddable to `Amount` too. Otherwise you mixed to concepts.
Have you check if the database which is generated by hibernate has the expected schema?
I hope this helps. Can't create an example at the moment.

Comment: `AccountBalance` as an embeddable is of couse annotated with `@Embeddable` (was not in my original excerpt). 

Using `Amount`as an embeddable was the first consideration. This is not possible though, since this object is used on client and server side and therefore can not contain JPA annotations.

The database is not created at all, it fails while checking all the JPA annotations.
I will test how it looks, when I add `updatable = false, insertable = false` again.

Comment: Using `Amount` as an Embeddable is not possible by design.
When setting `insertable`and `updatable` to `true`, the columns are not created at all.

After some debugging I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in hibernate and fixed it locally with a small patch that can be found here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11465